# Can you teleport to Rek'sai tunnels?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can allied champions teleport to my tunnels when I'm playing the champion Rek'sai? Does it matter if the tunnel is on cooldown for being recently traveled through by the Rek'sai?

Comment: I didnt know he was released yet. I'm definitely trying this when i get home tonight but i think someone else has tried this by then. Good question though!

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma *she ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use teleport on tunnels. I don't have any proofs but I successfully teleported myself to a tunnel during a game. I don't remember if the tunnel was on cooldown or not but I don't think it matters.

There is a message here that confirms it: (In french)

http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2013782